# How to directly run the examples of "man" for a particular function

Tags: command-line, find, manpage

**man** function are best way for learning new information in Ubuntu. They are the most extensive source possible. Every **man** has a section of **Example (in majority of cases),my query is on ways to use it without opening man and then copy-pasting the lines. Let me elaborate further below.

Suppose I am wishing to learn about the find function. I type

```
man find
```

My query is

I wish to directly run the example section of the **man** so that I can get a practical understanding on seeing outputs. How to directly run the examples of the man in terminal quickly?

In the above example of **man find**, the example codes were

```
EXAMPLES
       find /tmp -name core -type f -print | xargs /bin/rm -f

       Find files named core in or below the directory /tmp and delete them.  Note that this will work incorrectly if there are any filenames containing newlines, single or double quotes, or spaces.

       find /tmp -name core -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f

       Find files named core in or below the directory /tmp and delete them, processing filenames in such a way that file or directory names containing single or double quotes,  spaces  or  newlines
       are correctly handled.  The -name test comes before the -type test in order to avoid having to call stat(2) on every file.

       find . -type f -exec file '{}' \;

       Runs  `file'  on every file in or below the current directory.  Notice that the braces are enclosed in single quote marks to protect them from interpretation as shell script punctuation.  The
       semicolon is similarly protected by the use of a backslash, though single quotes could have been used in that case also.
```

One of the solution on way to just view the example directly in terminal (which I could think off) is

```
man find | grep -i "example" -C 2
```

Ofcourse, this did not take me to the example section and in turn help me in running it

Comment: To jump to the `EXAMPLES` section you could pass it as a search pattern to the default pager ex `LESS=+/^EXAMPLES man find`. I'm not sure how to go from there (aside from simply copying and pasting with the mouse/clipboard for example)

Comment: Thanks this seems to solve the problem at least halfway.

Comment: @muru thanks for the link. Was very helpful for understanding.